# SQL date conversion to written date

Tags: sql

Hi everyone I have a date in the format DD/MM/YYYY how do I convert it to the newDate format displayed below?

```
Date      |Newdate type
05/02/2017|Sunday 5 March 2017
04/02/2017|Saturday 4 March 2017
```

USING a SQL front end based on Microsoft jet

Comment: Column Date's data type? Which dbms are you using? (Most products are far from ANSI SQL compliant when it comes to date/time.)

Comment: SQl and a .dbf file

Comment: SQL is a language, specified by ISO/ANSI. Unfortunately many products don't follow the standard specification when it comes to date/time. That's why you really should tell us which dbms product you're using here.

Comment: A .DBF file and a sql interpreter tool that allows you to run commands directly on the data

Comment: Have you looked att this site: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp

Comment: you just load the file type in a command and it outputs the result

Comment: sorry that doesn't seem to work

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?  ("SQL" is **not** a DBMS product, it's a query language)

Comment: This is clear in the documentation.

Comment: as I have said again and again A .DBF file that is directly run using a SQL interpreter

Answer (score 2):

managed to find an answer

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634398.aspx

FORMAT(column,'dddd dd MMMM yyyy ')

Comment: That being the case, I recommend deleting the question.